# How to solve this google extension problem

Tags: google-chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Reading Time",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "I don't know what it does",
    "icons": {
      "128": "images/icon-128.png",
      "16": "images/icon-16.png"
    },
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "hello.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
          "matches": [
            "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/*",
            "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/*",
            "https://en.wikipedia.org/*"
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
const article = document.querySelector("article");
console.log("article one");
// `document.querySelector` may return null if the selector doesn't match anything.
if (article) {
  console.log("Content script is running");
  const text = article.textContent;
  const wordMatchRegExp = /[^\s]+/g; // Regular expression
  const words = text.matchAll(wordMatchRegExp);
  // matchAll returns an iterator, convert to array to get word count
  const wordCount = [...words].length;
  const readingTime = Math.round(wordCount / 200);
  const badge = document.createElement("p");
  // Use the same styling as the publish information in an article's header
  badge.classList.add("color-secondary-text", "type--caption");
  badge.textContent = `⏱️ ${readingTime} min read`;

  // Support for API reference docs
  const heading = article.querySelector("h1");
  // Support for article docs with date
  const date = article.querySelector("time")?.parentNode;

  (date ?? heading).insertAdjacentElement("afterend", badge);
  console.log("Badge inserted");

}
```

hello.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> what's up</h1>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I am learning how to create a google extension and , i have been following https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/ for that and following their teaching i have created a extension named Reading Time but it doesn't work , i thought it would give me how much time someone would need to read through the whole document maybe im understanding it in a wrong way can someone explain to me what this is suppose to do and also how can i make it to show the reading time in the web page or somewhere so that i can see it is working fine.

Comment: Looks fine, so you'll need to debug your content script in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
how do i do it i tried adding console.log() statements before and after if statement in content.js file but nothing is being printed in the console .

Comment: @wOxxOm can u help me do it im still just a beginner and there aren't many resources related to it in the internet

Comment: You need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm thankyou sir , really appreciate your help. Is there any website or anyonline commuinty where i can ask questions to someone if i get stuck in some problem other than stackoverflow?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions